# Get nearest nonzero pixel of a binary image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

The question is really simple but I cannot find an easy solution. 
So I want to extract the index of the nearest nonzero pixel of a binary image, constrained to a mask.

In sum, I want the INDX from "bwdist" but constrained to a mask:

```
[D,INDX]=bwdist(BW,'quasi-euclidean');
```

After doing some research I found out that "bwdistgeodesic" allows to define a mask, yet does not provide the index.

```
D = bwdistgeodesic(mask,BW,'quasi-euclidean');
```

Can anyone help here?

Comment: Why don't you apply the mask to your binary image before calculating the index and distance?

Comment: because that does not solve it. the idea is to get the minimum distance constrained to a certain path.